# Clojure macro to "insert" code from a file

Tags: macros, clojure

I have a file containing some forms, e.g.

```
(clojure.core/defn x [] (clojure.core/+ 5 7))
(clojure.core/defn y [a] (clojure.core/+ a 5))
```

that I want to be "inserted" into another file of Clojure code before runtime.

Presumably, I can use a macro to do this. I've tried writing a macro that reads the file and calls `load-string` on the string, but this causes the forms to be directly evaluated within the macro.

i.e. given the file above, I want

```
(some-other-code) ...

(my-macro)

(some-more-other-code)
```

to expand to

```
(some-other-code) ...

(clojure.core/defn x [] (clojure.core/+ 5 7))
(clojure.core/defn y [a] (clojure.core/+ a 5))

(some-more-other-code)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a simple (use 'namespace) at the point you want to bring in those functions?

Anyway, here is the code that I think does the trick:

```
(defn stream []
  (java.io.PushbackReader. (clojure.java.io/reader (clojure.java.io/file "foo.clj"))))

(defmacro insert []
  (let [content (with-open [s (stream)]
                  (loop [forms-so-far []]
                    (if-let [next-form (read s false nil)]
                      (recur (conj forms-so-far next-form))
                      forms-so-far)))]
    `(do ~@content)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with the built-in `load` function:

```
;; assuming foo.clj is on the classpath
(load "foo")
```

Clojure itself does this to split `clojure.core` into several files, see the lines immediately following [this one](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.5.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6152) in the sources of the 1.5.1 release. Also note the `(in-ns 'clojure.core)` at the top of the files being loaded in this way.

Of course using a macro is more flexible, as it allows you to inject code in arbitrary places, transform it in arbitrary ways etc. If you only want to divvy up a namespace between multiple files, however, `load` will be simpler.